# How to process huge datasets in kedro

Tags: python, kedro

I have pretty big (~200Gb, ~20M lines) raw jsonl dataset. I need to extract important properties from there and store the intermediate dataset in csv for further conversion into something like HDF5, parquet, etc. Obviously, I can't use `JSONDataSet` for loading raw dataset, because it utilizes `pandas.read_json` under the hood, and using pandas for the dataset of such size sounds like a bad idea. So I'm thinking about reading the raw dataset line by line, process and append processed data line by line to the intermediate dataset.

What I can't understand is how to make this compatible with `AbstractDataSet` with its `_load` and `_save` methods.

P.S. I understand I can move this out of kedro's context, and introduce preprocessed dataset as a raw one, but that kinda breaks the whole idea of complete pipelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use pyspark to leverage lazy evaluation and batch execution. 
SparkDataSet is implemented in kedro.contib.io.spark_data_set

Sample catalog config for jsonl:

```
your_dataset_name:   
  type: kedro.contrib.io.pyspark.SparkDataSet
  filepath: "\file_path"
  file_format: json
  load_args:
    multiline: True
```

Comment: Just a small comment that a bit shorter import path `kedro.contrib.io.pyspark.SparkDataSet` will also do